# Read database entries from mysql in the form of dictionary in python

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: use mysqldb to import a MySQL table as a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180226/python-use-mysqldb-to-import-a-mysql-table-as-a-dictionary)

I currently get the db entry in the form of array using the commands

```
db_conn = mdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "username", passwd = "password", db = "db_name", charset='utf8')
cursor = db_conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I get the row values in the form of array. Can I get in the form of dictionary with column names as keys. I couldn't find any such command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cursor factory when you connect:

```
db_conn = mdb.connect(
    host="localhost", user="username", passwd="password", db="db_name",
    charset='utf8', cursorclass=mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```