# Python TypeError: 'long' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python code that needs to login the user and also do the validation of inputs like check if password is good or if user excists, but I keep getting this error **TypeError: 'long' object is not subscriptable**??

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if g.user:
        return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="", db="cs324", host="127.0.0.1")
        c=db.cursor()
        user = c.execute('''select * from user where
            username = %s''', [request.form['username']])
        if user is None:
            error = ('Wrong username!')
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'],
                                     request.form['password']):
            error = ('Wrong password!')
        else:
            session['user_id'] = user['user_id']
            return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

It seems like the error occurs at the line when it checks for password and when session need to start. Any clues how I could fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of calling `cursor.execute` is the number of rows affected, not the result of the query. To get that, you need to call `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchall()` if you have several rows you want to iterate over.

Note that your code still won't work though, because the API does not return a dictionary, rather a tuple of values, so you can't do `user['password']`. If you want a dictionary, you need to use a DictCursor, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180226/python-use-mysqldb-to-import-a-mysql-table-as-a-dictionary). Otherwise you'll simply need to refer to the columns by number: `user[0]` etc. That would be clearer if you specified which columns you wanted in the SELECT query in the first place.