# Python - Returning the output as a dictionary - MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have coded a class to handle mysql connecting using the external modules but when I get data I want it to be returned like:

```
{ 'id': '1', 'username': 'Test'}
```

it's currently returned:

```
(1, u'Test')
```

The code which I use is:

```
def executeQuery(self, query):
    if(self.mysqlSuccess):
        cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
            print row
executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `users`')
```

Comment: not exactly a duplicated, but very close (and maybe the answer that op needs) :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: use mysqldb to import a MySQL table as a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180226/python-use-mysqldb-to-import-a-mysql-table-as-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 16):

I found an answer to my problem when your defining the cursor you do it like this

```
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

and the mysql package I was using is mysql.connector

Comment: I've been using namedtuple for weeks to acomplish a simliar result, thanks

Comment: It should be something like `connection.cursor` instead of `db.cursor`, or?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a DictCursor when initializing your connection to MySQL.

```
import MySQLdb.cursors

cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='joe', passwd='password', db='dbname',
                      cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

If you are using a diff mysql package then just check the docs for `DictCursor`.