# Data from MYSQL to Dictionary

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I'll start to say that I am new to Python, so maybe this is a wierd problem,

I got a db with 3 row, I want to loop them in an dictionary, but i only get one
row shown on the site, so it's some kind af overwriting every time it loops.

```
from dbConnect import connect

c, conn = connect()

ranks = c.execute("SELECT * FROM ranks ORDER BY rankid ASC;")

ranks = c.fetchall()

def ranksddl():
   rank_dict = {}

for rank in ranks:
    rank_dict[rank] = rank[2]

return rank_dict
```

Comment: Related? [DictCursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180226/python-use-mysqldb-to-import-a-mysql-table-as-a-dictionary).

Comment: In your for loop you are assigning the same value -- rank[2] -- to each element in the dictionary (rank_dict). Is that your intention? I think you likely want 
    for rank in ranks:
    rank_dict[rank] = rank

Comment: you probably want `rank_dict['rank'] = rank` (quotes around the  rank inside the square brackets).

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
ranks = ranks.fetchall()
```

and not

```
ranks = c.fetchall()
```

to get all of the results because the result of the query is stored in the first `ranks` variable. So if you want to get all the results in one go you should use `fetchall()` method on that variable and not on the cursor.